# Getting NULL value when click on commandbutton

Tags: java, mysql, primefaces, managed-bean

When click on commandButton ipsDetail values all are NULL in manageBean. in same pages other table data i get but following primefaces datatable not work properly.

XHTML file :

```
<p:dataTable id="invoiceTable" var="ipsDetail"
        value="#{invoiceBean.ipsDetails}" border="1" editable="true">


        <p:column headerText="Sr. No.">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ipsDetail.serialNumber}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{ipsDetail.serialNumber}" size="3" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Description of Goods">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ipsDetail.descriptionOfGoodsOrService}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputTextarea value="#{ipsDetail.descriptionOfGoodsOrService}" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="HSN Code">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ipsDetail.hsnCode}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{ipsDetail.hsnCode}" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Quantity">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ipsDetail.quantity}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{ipsDetail.quantity}" size="3" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Rate">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ipsDetail.rate}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{ipsDetail.rate}" size="3" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Percentage Discount">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ipsDetail.percentDiscount}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{ipsDetail.percentDiscount}" size="2" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Amount">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{invoiceBean.amount}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.amount}" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <p:rowEditor />
        </p:column>


        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="Add New Row"
                actionListener="#{invoiceBean.addRow}" update="invoiceTable"
                process="@this invoiceTable"
                oncomplete="jQuery('.ui-datatable-data tr').last().find('span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function(){jQuery(this).click()});" />
        </f:facet>

    </p:dataTable>
 <p:commandButton value="Add Invoice"
        action="#{invoiceBean.getInvoiceData()}" ajax="false" />
```

Manage Beans : invoiceBean it store all ipsDetail.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "invoiceBean", eager = true)
@ViewScoped
public class InvoiceBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String invoiceNumber;
private Date date;
private String deliveryNote;
private String modeOfPayment;
private int supplierReference;
private String otherReference;
private String buyerName;
private Date dispatchDocumentDate;
private String dispatchThrough;
private String destination;
private String email;
private String termsOfdelivery;
private String buyerOrderNumber;
private int amount;

private int serialNumber;
private String descriptionOfGoodsOrService;
private String hsnCode;
private int quantity;
private int rate;
private int percentDiscount;
private float vat;
private float serviceTax;

private int total;

private List<Invoice> invoices;
private List<InvoiceProductsServicesDetail> ipsDetails;
private Invoice invoice;
private InvoiceProductsServicesDetail ipsDetail;


public List<Invoice> getInvoices() {

    InvoiceDao invoiceDao = new InvoiceDao();
    invoices = invoiceDao.getInvoiceData();

    return invoices;
}


public void setInvoices(List<Invoice> invoices) {
    if (invoices != null) {
        this.invoices.add(new Invoice());
    }
}

public void saveInvoiceData() {
    InvoiceDao invoiceDao = new InvoiceDao();
    invoice = new Invoice();
    ipsDetail = new InvoiceProductsServicesDetail();
    try {
        if (invoice != null && ipsDetail != null) {
            invoice.setInvoiceNumber(getInvoiceNumber());
            invoice.setDate(date);
            invoice.setDeliveryNote(deliveryNote);
            invoice.setModeOfPayment(modeOfPayment);
            invoice.setSupplierReference(supplierReference);
            invoice.setOtherReference(otherReference);
            invoice.setBuyerName(buyerName);
            invoice.setBuyerOrderNumber(buyerOrderNumber);
            invoice.setOrderDate(new Date());
            invoice.setDispatchDocumentDate(dispatchDocumentDate);
            invoice.setDispatchThrough(dispatchThrough);
            invoice.setDestination(destination);
            invoice.setTermsOfdelivery(termsOfdelivery);
            invoice.setEmail(email);
            invoice.setTotal(total);
            // invoiceDao.insertInvoice(invoice);

            System.out.println(getAmount());

            ipsDetail
                    .setDescriptionOfGoodsOrService(getDescriptionOfGoodsOrService());
            ipsDetail.setHsnCode(hsnCode);
            ipsDetail.setInvoiceId(invoice.getId());
            ipsDetail.setPercentDiscount(percentDiscount);
            ipsDetail.setQuantity(quantity);
            ipsDetail.setRate(rate);
            ipsDetail.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
            ipsDetail.setServiceTax((float) 12.36);
            ipsDetail.setVat(5);
            invoiceDao.insertIpsDetail(ipsDetail);

            System.out.println("InvoiceBean.insertInvoice");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void addRow(){

    ipsDetail = new InvoiceProductsServicesDetail();
    ipsDetails.add(ipsDetail);
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {

        DataTable table = (DataTable) facesContext.getViewRoot().findComponent("form:invoiceTable");

        UIComponent uiTable = ComponentUtils.findParentForm(facesContext, table);

        final AjaxBehavior behavior = new AjaxBehavior();
        RowEditEvent rowEditEvent = new RowEditEvent(uiTable, behavior, table.getRowData());


        rowEditEvent.setPhaseId(PhaseId.UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES);
        table.broadcast(rowEditEvent);


    } catch (AbortProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public InvoiceBean() {
    ipsDetails = new ArrayList<InvoiceProductsServicesDetail>();
}


public InvoiceProductsServicesDetail getIpsDetail() {
    return ipsDetail;
}

public void setIpsDetail(InvoiceProductsServicesDetail ipsDetail) {
    this.ipsDetail = ipsDetail;
}

public void setIpsDetails(List<InvoiceProductsServicesDetail> ipsDetails) {
    if(ipsDetails != null){
        this.ipsDetails.addAll(ipsDetails);
    }

}

public List<InvoiceProductsServicesDetail> getIpsDetails() {
    return ipsDetails;
    //return new InvoiceProductsServicesDetailDao().getIpsData() ;
}

public String getInvoiceNumber() {
    return invoiceNumber;
}

public void setInvoiceNumber(String invoiceNumber) {
    this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getDeliveryNote() {
    return deliveryNote;
}

public void setDeliveryNote(String deliveryNote) {
    this.deliveryNote = deliveryNote;
}

public String getModeOfPayment() {
    return modeOfPayment;
}

public void setModeOfPayment(String modeOfPayment) {
    this.modeOfPayment = modeOfPayment;
}

public int getSupplierReference() {
    return supplierReference;
}

public void setSupplierReference(int supplierReference) {
    this.supplierReference = supplierReference;
}

public String getOtherReference() {
    return otherReference;
}

public void setOtherReference(String otherReference) {
    this.otherReference = otherReference;
}

public String getBuyerName() {
    return buyerName;
}

public void setBuyerName(String buyerName) {
    this.buyerName = buyerName;
}

public Date getDispatchDocumentDate() {
    return dispatchDocumentDate;
}

public void setDispatchDocumentDate(Date dispatchDocumentDate) {
    this.dispatchDocumentDate = dispatchDocumentDate;
}

public String getDispatchThrough() {
    return dispatchThrough;
}

public void setDispatchThrough(String dispatchThrough) {
    this.dispatchThrough = dispatchThrough;
}

public String getDestination() {
    return destination;
}

public void setDestination(String destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getTermsOfdelivery() {
    return termsOfdelivery;
}

public void setTermsOfdelivery(String termsOfdelivery) {
    this.termsOfdelivery = termsOfdelivery;
}

public int getSerialNumber() {
    return serialNumber;
}

public void setSerialNumber(int serialNumber) {
    this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
}

public String getDescriptionOfGoodsOrService() {
    return descriptionOfGoodsOrService;
}

public void setDescriptionOfGoodsOrService(
        String descriptionOfGoodsOrService) {
    this.descriptionOfGoodsOrService = descriptionOfGoodsOrService;
}

public String getHsnCode() {
    return hsnCode;
}

public void setHsnCode(String hsnCode) {
    this.hsnCode = hsnCode;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public int getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(int rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public int getPercentDiscount() {
    return percentDiscount;
}

public void setPercentDiscount(int percentDiscount) {
    this.percentDiscount = percentDiscount;
}

public float getVat() {
    return vat;
}

public void setVat(float vat) {
    this.vat = vat;
}

public float getServiceTax() {
    return serviceTax;
}

public void setServiceTax(float serviceTax) {
    this.serviceTax = serviceTax;
}

public String getBuyerOrderNumber() {
    return buyerOrderNumber;
}

public void setBuyerOrderNumber(String buyerOrderNumber) {
    this.buyerOrderNumber = buyerOrderNumber;
}

public Invoice getInvoice() {
    return invoice;
}

public void setInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
    this.invoice = invoice;
}

public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public int getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(int total) {
    this.total = total;
}
}
```

i want to store all the data in mysql database table.

Comment: Is your input elements inside form tag?

Comment: yes i want to input inside the from tag and also from tag is used.

Comment: use action instead of actionListener

Comment: i try to use actionListener inside commandButton :(

Comment: Does your DAO implementation join or map the related InvoiceDetails? if so you should get those details in ipsDetails otherwise you are creating a new list for each use of the bean and will get null values each time.

Comment: YES i implemented DAO with map with mysql related to InvoiceDetails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the values in the invoice bean.

Once you have added a new Detail by clicking add you are putting the values into this new object. But you are then saving a new Detail in the saveInvoice bean and attempting to get the values from the properties in the bean. (Which are not being set and as such are NULL) This will not work as the properties are not mapped to the table.

You are also creating more work in the code than necessary and over complicating it. If you change the bean to get the Details of the new instance from the addRow method or update the properties in the cell editor it should work. You will probably also need to simplify some of the other code.

Note: I actually recommend you start from scratch. Use an iterative approach to the problem starting with addRow and then save. Debug is your friend.

Update the xhtml outputs to map to the properties. E.g:

```
<f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.($ipsDetail)}" size="3" />
                </f:facet>
```

Also: In your footer you make reference to an actionListener. Change this to an 'action' and remove the process. Have the addRow method add an empty row to the details list. Map this detail.

```
<p:commandButton value="Add New Row" oncomplete="clickFirstRow()"
                action="#{invoiceBean.addRow}" update="invoiceTable"
                 />
```

Also your save button could deal with the application and saving of the editable row by clicking all the rows to save.

```
<p:commandButton value="Save Invoice" ajax="false"
    onclick="tickAllRows()" action="#{invoiceBean.saveInvoiceData}" />
```

Comment: thanks for give me suggestion but value of all datatable are NULL.

Comment: Post the bean so you can show that you properly get all the rows in ipsDetails

Comment: i do not want to retrieve data from DAO i just want to store data in DAO but ipsDetail values all are NULL.

Comment: Sorry mate I misunderstood your issue. I have updated the answer accordingly. If you miss what I am saying I will further add a working example for you.

Comment: Does this mean you got now understand what was going wrong? I hope so.

Answer (score -1):

try changing the scope of your bean to be "request" or "session" instead of "view scope"